# Better handling of indentation and the TAB key when editing posts

Tags: script, editing, keyboard-shortcuts

[image: indenting]

### About

This user script changes the behavior of a few keys (most notably the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key) within the post editor to behave more like it does in IDEs or text editors:

- When multiple lines are selected, <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> indent and dedent these lines
- When nothing is selected, <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> insert or remove whitespace to align the cursor on a tab boundary
- When the cursor is within the left margin of a line, <kbd>Backspace</kbd> removes whitespace to align the cursor on a tab boundary (in other words, it may delete more than just one space character)
- On indented lines, the <kbd>Home</kbd> key toggles the cursor between the *actual* beginning of the line and the beginning of the real content (in other words, it jumps back and forth to before and after the leading whitespace). This only happens on lines that are indented by at least four spaces or a tab, since it can be confusing for the following reason: When you press <kbd>Home</kbd> in the text editor, you expect the cursor to jump to the beginning of the line *as it is displayed*, which (due to wrapping) may be different from the actual previous newline character.
- So you don't have to reach for the mouse to tab out of the editor you can press *and release* the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, and the next key press will not be intercepted; thus <kbd>Tab</kbd> takes you out of the editor. Pressing and releasing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> will grey out the text editor until the next keystroke to clarify this. If you think this is too awkward, I'm open to other suggestions, but there should be some way to tab out of the editor .

Note that this will never insert TAB characters, only spaces. It does however handle already-present TABs, and it handles them the same way the Markdown converter does.

Feedback very welcome, except for discussions about a) tabs vs. spaces, and b) tab width :)

#### Download

[Click this link to install it](https://bitbucket.org/balpha/se-tab-edting/raw/tip/tab-editing.user.js) [[Archive link 2017-03-18](https://web.archive.org/web/20170318173000/https://bitbucket.org/balpha/se-tab-edting/raw/tip/tab-editing.user.js)]

Comment: Question: (awesome script by the way!) how does the auto-update feature work around the same-domain restriction for `localStorage`?

Comment: It doesn't. It checks for updates on every SE site you visit.

Comment: Great script, when creating questions. I tried to use its features when editing a question accessed through the review-beta system, with no success. Is this the right place to file this bug?

Comment: @balpha Great script! I'm bookmarking it. How about auto indentation? It will be great if, when I press Enter, the new line can be indented automatically to match the previous line's indentation. _As a bonus,_ it could also extra-indent the line after opening brackets by one step and de-indent closing brackets by one step.

Comment: I'd like to suggest dropping the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key triggering if the tab is sent to the browser or not, and instead using the <kbd>esc</kbd> key. People won't unintentionally press the esc key in everyday editing, so that would seem like a much better key to trigger this on imo.

Comment: @joeytje50 Esc already has a meaning during editing, so this is out of the question.

Comment: @balpha What does it do then? I tried googling this, but that came up with questions on SO about binding the esc key, and searching on meta.SO didn't help either.

Comment: @joeytje50 What the Esc key is there for -- it cancels the editing. Same as clicking the "cancel" link. Note that I'm talking about *editing*, not *suggesting edits*; the latter has no cancel link because it doesn't need one (since it doesn't happen inline, but on a new page).

Comment: Note that as of Chrome 35 (late May 2014) you can't install user scripts that aren't in the web store, even if you download them locally. Get TamperMonkey as a workaround, but the author may wish to add the script to the Chrome Web Store for easier installation for Chrome users.

Comment: Or install the script manually http://stackapps.com/tags/script/info

Comment: @Dan You can't, as of Chrome 35. You need to use TamperMonkey. @balpha You may want to add that `Shift-Tab` accessibility shortcut can be achieved (when using your add-on) as follows: **1.** Press and hold down `Shift` key. **2.** Press and **release** `Ctrl` while still holding down `Shift` (text area becomes grey). **3.** Press the `Tab` key. The `Shift-Tab` action will be performed. You can now release the `Shift` key.

Comment: Any chance you can get this working in the suggested edits queue?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I have given up on installing user scripts directly as Chrome extensions. I use TamperMonkey instead now.

Comment: This userscript has stopped working since SO switched to https. I've created a pullrequest [here](https://bitbucket.org/balpha/se-tab-edting/pull-requests/3/fix-https-problem-address-tampermonkey/diff) that fixes this problem.

Comment: @TotZam All the links in this post are dead. Do you currently have a working version installed that you can put up somewhere? The license looks to be MIT, so it should be OK

Comment: @CertainPerformance I don't and it looks like I just have a stale pull request in my BitBucket account. While it appears that the OP no longer works at SO, it looks like he is still an active user, so I would say it's up to him if he wants to make that code available to the community again.

Answer (score 15):

### Inheriting indention when pressing enter

What I'd like to suggest is that if you press <kbd>enter</kbd>, the indentation is copied from the line you're coming from, and then automatically put before the next line. This would make it a bit easier to type out code on SO. Of course this would create the problem that people who would want to end their code would be required to press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> or <kbd>backspace</kbd>, so to fix that, you could make it that it stops inheriting previous indentation when pressing enter with only whitespace on that line. For example, with the things between `[]` being inserted by the script; <kbd>⇆ Tab</kbd>, <kbd>↵ Enter</kbd> and <kbd>← Backspace</kbd>:

```
[⇆ ]lorem Ipsum(dolor) {
[↵ ]    sit amet;
[↵←]}
[↵ ]|
```

and after pressing enter again, it inserts a newline, but removes the previously added indentation, so pressing enter again would change that to the following:

```
[⇆ ]lorem Ipsum(dolor) {
[↵ ]    sit amet;
[↵←]}

|
```

So in summary, it would do this when pressing enter:

- ...insert the exact same amount of indentation as the previous line had
- ...and only whitespace exists on the line, remove that whitespace and insert an enter

### Other keys triggering default behaviour

I'd like to suggest using <del>*either alt+shift or ctrl+alt*</del> the <kbd>esc</kbd> key instead of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>. It would happen a lot less that people would use esc without actually meaning to do this. The <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key is used a lot in other situations, such as copy/pasting, backspacing full words, etc. In those situations where you use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> it might happen (and does regularly happen) that you press the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key without actually intending to trigger the white-out.

Answer (score 4):

This uses the jQuery [`.on(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) feature which is only available in 1.7 and up.  Careers is still using an older version and you get an exception on every page right now with this installed.

We will be updating soon, but it would be nice if you could add a config page to turn it on/off for each site.

Comment: Good point; I've added a check to make sure it's only run on a plain ol' Stack Exchange Q&A site. It wouldn't be a problem to convert this to work with jQuery 1.5, but that isn't really necessary.

Answer (score 4):

It would be nice to have a script option to adjust the indentation size. I, for one, would probably find an indent size of two spaces helpful.

(Many questions I'm editing to correct indentation are not aligned nicely on four-space indents.)

Comment: An option to switch between spaces and tab would also be nice! :)

Comment: @Kyle_the_hacker Would it? Stack Exchange sits only recognise spaces for indenting code.

Comment: @Duncan_Jones: No it don't only support spaces, but also tabs. Just try. ;)

Comment: @Kyle_the_hacker You are correct!

Answer (score 4):

With the recent network-wide HTTPS switch, the `include`'s should change to:

```
// @include        https://stackoverflow.com/*
// @include        https://*.stackoverflow.com/*
```

Also, in case of editing a question in the review queues, I noticed that the script wasn't working. The problem was in this line:

```
$("#mainbar").on("keydown", ".wmd-input", function (evt) { ...
```

As one goes through various posts in the queue, I suspect the `mainbar` element itself would be removed/replaced. A fix to that would be:

```
$("#content").on("keydown", ".wmd-input", function (evt) { ...
```

I suspect that the other event listener might need to be changed similarly for <kbd>Ctrl + Tab</kbd> combo.

Comment: Better off using `@match` so that http/https and domain+subdomains can all be covered by a single rule per domain. e.g.  `//@match          *://*.stackoverflow.com/*` covers Stack Overflow & Meta Stack Overflow, and `//@match          *://*.stackexchange.com/*` covers all sites at `subdomain.stackexchange.com`, and their meta sites.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the `@include`s in the script header for the following simplified `@match`es:

```javascript
// @match           *://*.askubuntu.com/questions*
// @match           *://*.mathoverflow.net/questions*
// @match           *://*.serverfault.com/questions*
// @match           *://*.stackapps.com/questions*
// @match           *://*.stackexchange.com/questions*
// @match           *://*.stackoverflow.com/questions*
// @match           *://*.superuser.com/questions*
// @exclude         http://chat.*
// @exclude         http://blog.*
// @exclude         http://careers.stackoverflow.com.*
```

Those will limit the script only to pages under `/questions` and to restrict only to individual questions, changed the following check at the start:

```javascript
// are we really really on a Stack Exchange site?
if (!(window.StackExchange && StackExchange.options.routeName.indexOf('Questions/Show') !== -1 ))
    return;
```

Comment: This would disable the script on edit pages like https://stackapps.com/posts/4912/edit.

Answer (score 0):

### Tabbing out of the editor

While tapping <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and then <kbd>tab</kbd> works well for tabbing out of the editor, i'd like to suggest an improvement. Unless the cursor is at the beginning of the line, it should tab out. Intending should only occur at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Indenting yes, but there are other valid reasons for tabbing, e.g. tabular data, lining up comments, etc.

Comment: So how about automatically tabbing out if it's at the very end of the textbox?