# Unable to install script on Chrome

Tags: support, google-chrome, scripts

I posted [a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/186618/how-to-easily-unindent-a-block-of-code/186621#186621) on Meta Stack Overflow, and from there I was directed to install [this script](https://stackapps.com/questions/3247/better-handling-of-indentation-and-the-tab-key-when-editing-posts#_=_).

When trying to install the script in Chrome, I get the following error:

> Apps, extensions and user scripts cannot be added from this website.

Is there another way I can get the script or similar extension for Chrome?

Comment: This is off topic here.  Belongs on [su].  It's just a standard script-install question, even if it's about a script listed on this site.

Comment: No that post is *announcing* /releasing/posting the script.  There's a difference.  Also installing scripts is already covered [here](http://stackapps.com/tags/script/info), plus on [su], plus on [so].  General script-install questions go in [su].  Programming script questions go on [so].  *Actual scripts* for [se] or questions about the SE API go here.

Comment: No need to delete.  If enough people agree it's a duplicate it will get closed. (It may take a few days on this site.)  Not all closed questions are deleted and dupes can have value in pointing searches to the right location.

Comment: (1) That's not [su] -- where the question belongs (if it wasn't a dupe)!  (2) Why did you do that?  You already have your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

### 1. Tampermonkey

1. Install [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) for Chrome;
2. Click [the script](https://bitbucket.org/balpha/se-tab-edting/raw/tip/tab-editing.user.js) to install it.

### 2. Vanilla Chrome

1. Copy the code and save it to a file called `anything.user.js`;
2. In Chrome, go to `chrome://extensions/` (*Tools* > *More Tools* > *Extensions*);
3. Open the folder you saved the script to and drag it onto the *Extensions* dialog.